# Sentence structure grammar books

Tags: discussion

Could you advice to me literature to classify correct English sentences structure? Russian grammar book provides incorrect names of grammatical structures hence I'm confusing to find a little more about sentence construction, IMO.

Comment: Questions requesting resources are ordinarily posted to [Meta]. I don't think Russian treatments of English syntax are *incorrect*, but they tend to employ different analyses and terms than English-language treatments. I recommend Huddleston and Pullum, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*--or if you're capable of really heavy lifting their *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (*CGEL*).